# Turn off XSD validation of spring files

Tags: java, xml, spring

Spring tries to validate xml confniguration files against xml schemas. Which is fine, but there might be cases when the validation fails (outdated schema, for example). Is there a way to turn off xsd validation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this Spring JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5014 - has both the team's comments on why they won't directly build it in as well as an example of how to implement yourself.